# Invalid cross-thread access

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am getting an Invalid cross-thread access when I try to use a BitMapImage in my cam_CaptureImageAvailable method, I tried using a Dispatcher but that gave me a Cannot access a closed Stream error, System.ObjectDisposedException was unhandled.

```
// Informs when full resolution picture has been taken, saves to local media library and isolated storage.
    void cam_CaptureImageAvailable(object sender, Microsoft.Devices.ContentReadyEventArgs e)
    {

        string fileName = folderName+"\\MyImage" + savedCounter + ".jpg";

        try
        {   // Write message to the UI thread.
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
            {
                txtDebug.Text = "Captured image available, saving picture ," + fileName;
            });

            // Save picture to the library camera roll.
            //library.SavePictureToCameraRoll(fileName, e.ImageStream);


            // Write message to the UI thread.
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
            {
                //txtDebug.Text = "Picture has been saved.";

            });

            // Set the position of the stream back to start
            e.ImageStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);


            // Save picture as JPEG to isolated storage.
            using (IsolatedStorageFile isStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream targetStream = isStore.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {

                    // Initialize the buffer for 4KB disk pages.
                    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
                    int bytesRead = -1;

                    // Copy the image to isolated storage. 
                    while ((bytesRead = e.ImageStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        targetStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);

                    }

                }

                var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(); 
                bitmapImage.SetSource(e.ImageStream); 
                WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage);
                IsolatedStorageFile myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication(); 
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream myFileStream = myStore.CreateFile(fileName)) 
                { 
                    wb.SaveJpeg(myFileStream, 10, 10, 0, 70); 
                }

            }





        }
        finally
        {
            // Close image stream
            e.ImageStream.Close();
        }

    }
```

Tried this as well

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
                {
                    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                    bitmapImage.SetSource(e.ImageStream);
                    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage);
                    IsolatedStorageFile myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream myFileStream = myStore.CreateFile(fileName))
                    {
                        wb.SaveJpeg(myFileStream, 10, 10, 0, 70);//compressing image
                    }
                });
```

Can anyone help me I would really appreciate it thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create the `BitmapImage` and the `WriteableBitmap` on the UI thread because they are `DependencyObject`s.

The reason you get the `ObjectDisposedException` error is that the stream for the image is closed already when the dispatcher handles your request.

Did you try moving that code into your Dispatcher invocation?

```
 e.ImageStream.Close();
```

The code for the dispatcher does not get executed immediately but at a later point in time, but you have closed the stream already.

If that doesnt work, then you could workaround your problem by reading the stream to memory in `CaptureImageAvailable` and then pass that `MemoryStream` as source to your `BitmapImage`.

Comment: Hi pivotnig, I am using memory stream and it works but I am only getting the first Image every time I take a picture, here is the code I am using code `e.ImageStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);e.ImageStream.CopyTo(ms);` and in the dispatcher I have `var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();bitmapImage.SetSource(ms);WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage);`   Thanks for your help

Comment: I am only getting the first Image every time I take a picture

Comment: It's Ok I had the Memory stream as a global variable:)